# Making a Exp bar with javascript not working?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a experince bar for a game. I got it to increase and when the bar is full it level ups the person but I can't get the bar to reset, and if i gain anymore xp it will level up the person again.

```js
var exp_width = document.getElementById('xp-progress').offsetWidth

var kingdom = {
  type: "weak",
  lvl: 1,
}
document.getElementById('kingdom').innerHTML = kingdom.lvl
document.getElementById('type').innerHTML = kingdom.type

function lvl() {
  kingdom.lvl += 1
  document.getElementById('kingdom').innerHTML = kingdom.lvl
  if (charmander.lvl == 36) {
    kingdom.type = "weakish"
    document.getElementById('type').innerHTML = kingdom.type

  }
}

function exps() {
  document.getElementById('xp-progress').style.width = exp_width += 32;
  if (exp_width >= 200) {
    lvl();
    document.getElementById('xp-progress').style.width == 1;
    exp_width == 1;
  }
}
```

```css
#xp-bar {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #EEE;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #999;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}
#xp-progress {
  display: block;
  width: 1px;
  height: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: green;
  border-right: solid 1px #6C0;
}
```

```html
<a id="kingdom"></a>
<br>
<a id="type"></a>
<br>
<button onClick="exps()">Progress</button>
<div id="xp-bar">
  <div id="xp-progress"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add at the end of every lvl code a lvl.set (0) but I think that you need to change the var name to for every lvl stadium

Sorry for the answer I cannot write comments on mobile